# Extension to algorithm of breaking paragraph into lines

Tags: line-breaking

Donald Knuth writes in his book «Digital Typography», pages 129-130:

> Notice that another aid to line breaking in Latin at that time was to replace an *m* or *n* by a tilde on previous vowel (e.g., 'premiũ' for premium and 'mũdo' for mundo); an extension to the box/glue/penalty algebra would be needed to include such options in TeX's line-breaking algorithm.

Was such an extension ever implemented?

It would be great to use optional abbreviations. And in Church Slavonic typography there are methods similar to the one described here.

Comment: you could certainly do such a thing in luatex, not sure if it's actually implemented anywhere, basically try the paragraph with and without the substitution and accept the one with the best breaks. As for hyphenation you would probably only want to try some of the substitutions to avoid exponential explosion if you tried every combination, but that's just details....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it isn't really a question of trying with and without as that was not a yes or no on the whole paragraph but on individual occurrances as needed as I understand it. Theat means what you need is a full fledged extension of supporting alternate content and have the dynamic programming approach support that. Short answer to the abve question: no never been done to my knowledge; doable yes, especially now with luatex, but far from trivial.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach certainly needs to be done on each character (in principle) so you'd need to come up with some heuristic to avoid trying all combinations. although actually I was wondering if you could use microtype with the existing character protrusion support: use some character and tell microtype it can expand it between a `u` and and a `um` and let the engine set as usual then in the callback after line breaking replace narrow instances of the marker by ũ and wide ones by `um`  if you can use real adjustment of the  width of u to make the available widths more continuous, it might work